# iOS Universal app Default images

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-universal-app

In an universal app when I place launch images for iPhone the same is taken for iPad and warning is shown, I have give name like Default.png (iPhone) Default@2x.png (retina) and Default~ipad.png (for iPad). Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Go to XCode, click on the project name in the Project Navigator on the left, click on your app target in the list in the middle of the screen and choose the 'Summary' tab.

Now drag (from finder) and drop your images on the App Icons for both the iPhone and the iPad version.
XCode will take care of the proper naming and placing of your icon files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jelle, i did it in the same way but still it is giving warning. The issue is it is taking iphone's retina launch image for ipad also.

Comment: Do you use the correct image sizes? Use the full screen sizes, like 2048x1536 and 1536x2048 for iPad.

Comment: Note that the sizes jpalten recommends are only correct if the status bar is hidden upon app launch.  If you try to use those sizes for the iPad default images and don't have the status bar set to hidden, it will use the iPhone default images instead.  At least that's the behavior I'm seeing.